# How to find and solve an "Exception" error in google app script?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script

I have an app script that gets values from a spreed sheet and updates a Google forms. It was working normally until I did "SOMETHING?" and it all stopped working. I had to make a new one, that "works" but returns an error every time. How can I find and fix that error?

**The Script:**

```
const Tasks = () => {
  const GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME = 'Form Data';
  const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = '1m9Y78nRS-YjzwKS4Vpcy2JHvjuNYUzswAEmFDE-zIQo';

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const [header, ...data] = ss
    .getSheetByName(GOOGLE_SHEET_NAME)
    .getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues();

  const choices = {};
  header.forEach((title, i) => {
    choices[title] = data.map((d) => d[i]).filter((e) => e);
  });

  FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID)
    .getItems()
    .map((item) => ({
      item,
      values: choices[item.getTitle()],
    }))
    .filter((values) => values)
    .forEach(({ item, values }) => {
      switch (item.getType()) {
        case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
          item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
          item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
          item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(values);
          break;
        default:
        // ignore item
      }
    });
  ss.toast('Update Finished!!');
};
```

**What the Script pulls from the spreed sheet:**

```
Nome de Mestre:
Akmusth
Bakon
Bill
Borges
Brunão
Carlos André
Chris
Curvello
Danilo Carneiro
Douglas Bastos
Dudinha
Fragoso
Garrit
Genkai
Helton
John
Júnior Carvalho
Kobra
Léo
Liberal
Matheus Gravalos
Pedro Rolinsk
Pollux
Rafael Martins
Razec
Sh3ng
Tales Fox
Tatá
Tellindo
Thairony
Valber
Victor Hugo
Wesley Batista
Yami
```

**The Error:**

> Exception: Invalid Argument: values (line 30, file "Tasks")

**What I get at Stackdriver Logging:**

> Exception: invalid Argument: values
> at unknown function
> at Tasks(Tasks:24:6)

Comment: I thought that from the error message of `Invalid Argument: values`, `values` might be undefined. So when `if (!values) return;` is put after the line of `.forEach(({ item, values }) => {`, what result will you obtain? If that result might not be what you want, please confirm the header values and the title of each item on Google form. By the way, can I ask you about `SOMETHING` of `I did "SOMETHING?"`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which means provide a minimal example of a function with the appropriate table of data that we can use to generate the problem or you can just learn how to use the debugger and fix it yourself.

Comment: What are you expecting `values` to be?

Comment: @Tanaike, i added `if (!values) return;` like you said, and now it just works...

Comment: The `SOMETHING` was a new form I made, and it was to pull from the same sheet, different values, I got that to work, and every thing else stopped working. So I scraped all the old code and made a new one, that new one is the one I showed here.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, I think that it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.